# DynamoDB: Query on columns not present in the Schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the following table in my DynamoDB

```
Thread (id, userId, content)
```

With id being the primary key. I have not defined any sort key.

Now i need to retrieve a result based on the userId .. in short i need all the records in table containing a specific userId

```
userId = '123';
let queryParams = {
  TableName: tableName,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#userid': 'userid'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':userid': userId
  },
  KeyConditionExpression: "#userid = :userid" 
} 
dynamodb.query(queryParams, (err, data) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
});
```

when i run this, i get an error

```
Could not load items: ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: id
```

Can someone please let me know how can i query for all records containing the userId '123'??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you will need to [add a Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating) to your table that has userId as the primary key. Then you can query that index directly.

You must also include the name of the index in the query request ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.QueryAndScan.html)).

Comment: The sample code you provided does not include the index name. You must include the index name to query the index. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.QueryAndScan.html

Comment: Can you please add the above in your original answer, so that i can accept it..
It works, Thank you for the help!